Issue with Extreme Values in scPDSI and PDSI Calculations Using R's scPDSI Package
I'm encountering very high (e.g., Inf) and very low (e.g., < -2000) values in both scPDSI and conventional PDSI calculations using the scPDSI package in R. Package installed from this GitHub repo
Reproducible example:
I selected two pixels from my drought-mapping area as examples. In one case, the scPDSI values are abnormal, while the conventional PDSI values are normal. In the other case, the situation is reversed.
Example 1: Abnormal scPDSI, Normal PDSI
p_vector_1 <- c(229, 181, 21, 15, 192, 84, 55, 113, 199, 521, 328, 165, 606, 40, 14, 27, 83, 106, 63, 229, 95, 432, 382, 182, 99, 234, 28, 25, 43, 73, 132, 118, 209, 213, 392, 142, 287, 127, 44, 22, 134, 125, 194, 233, 229, 305, 382, 112, 440, 157, 11, 41, 102, 33, 85, 106, 152, 626, 255, 108)
pe_vector_1 <- c(12, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 11, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 11, 12, 19, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 12, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001)

scpdsi_values_1 <- scPDSI::pdsi(P = p_vector_1, PE = pe_vector_1, AWC = 113, start = 1961, sc = TRUE)$X
pdsi_values_1 <- scPDSI::pdsi(P = p_vector_1, PE = pe_vector_1, AWC = 113, start = 1961, sc = FALSE)$X

Example 2: Normal scPDSI, Abnormal PDSI
p_vector_2 <- c(792, 997, 336, 207, 259, 147, 29, 248, 594, 1136, 1144, 1108, 2012, 148, 184, 342, 88, 176, 37, 386, 325, 853, 1404, 1227, 378, 1161, 386, 304, 59, 135, 91, 126, 656, 504, 1238, 1254, 899, 739, 663, 363, 179, 189, 139, 335, 756, 625, 1052, 777, 1355, 968, 154, 466, 155, 66, 63, 150, 534, 1194, 683, 922)
pe_vector_2 <- c(0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001)

scpdsi_values_2 <- scPDSI::pdsi(P = p_vector_2, PE = pe_vector_2, AWC = 113, start = 1961, sc = TRUE)$X
pdsi_values_2 <- scPDSI::pdsi(P = p_vector_2, PE = pe_vector_2, AWC = 113, start = 1961, sc = FALSE)$X

In both examples, I replaced PE values of 0 with 0.0001 to avoid division by zero. However, I’m still seeing extreme scPDSI and PDSI values.
Is this expected when using the scPDSI package with very low PE values? I noticed it was removed from CRAN. Maybe the reason it was removed also caused the extreme values I see? If that's the case, is there a better way (or an alternative R package) to avoid these extreme results?

In addition to help on the extreme value issues, any tips on speeding up the process of spatRaster creation will be appreciated:
My objective is to generate a set of drought rasters across time, so my code loops through all pixels indices, generate a time-series PDSI vectors (5year *12 months = 60 elements in each vector) for all pixels. Results were saved in a 60-element list (pdsi_results <- vector("list", length = 60)), where each element is a matrix that saves the month-specific scPDSI/PDSI values for all pixels. The matrices are initiated as pdsi_results[[month_idx]] <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(base_raster), ncol = ncol(base_raster)), and values are filled using pdsi_results[[month_idx]][cell_index] <- pdsi_result[month_idx]. Then, I write the results to spatRasters. The extreme values in some pixels result in the spatRasters having an abnormal value range.
Thanks!
